# subtraction between sum of all elements of two symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let assume that I have an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ and I know $A^{-1}$. Now, I have a new matrix
$$M =  \begin{pmatrix}
  A & b \\
  b^T & c
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $b$ is a vector and $c$ is a single element which is $0$.

My goal is to find $\sum(M^{-1}) - \sum(A^{-1})$ in an efficient way (in low computational cost without inverting $M$), where $\sum(A)$ refers to sum of all the elements of A.

From bordering method, I know that $M^{-1}$ could be found easily:
$$M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1}+\frac{1}{k}A^{-1}bb^TA^{-1} & -\frac{1}{k}A^{-1}b \\
-\frac{1}{k}b^tA^{-1} & \frac{1}{k}
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $k=c-b^TA^{-1}b$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With $d=[\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n]^T:=A^{-1}b$, we have
$$
M^{-1}=\pmatrix{A^{-1}+\frac{1}{k}dd^T & -\frac{1}{k}d\\-\frac{1}{k}d^T&\frac{1}{k}}
$$
and hence the difference between the sums of the entries of $M^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ is the same as the sum of entries of
$$
\frac{1}{k}\pmatrix{dd^T & d \\ d^T & 1}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\Sigma(M^{-1})-\Sigma(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{k}\left[\Sigma(dd^T)-2\Sigma(d)+1\right]
=\frac{1}{k}(\sigma^2-2\sigma+1)=\frac{1}{k}(\sigma-1)^2,
$$
where
$$
\sigma:=\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_i.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is an efficient solution. Additionally, is it somehow possible to get rid of matrix multiplication in K to make to computational linear i.e., O(n)?

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub What do you mean exactly? In any case, you have to solve the system $Ad=b$ (or multiply $b$ by $A^{-1}$ if you have it explicitly). You can of course use $d$ to compute $k=c-b^TA^{-1}b=c-b^Td$.

Comment: I mean that could the manipulation of $$\Sigma(M^{-1}) - \Sigma(A^{-1})$$ somehow avoid  multiplication of matrices (in this case, $b^TA^{-1}b$). If the size of the matrices are large, the multiplication will be time consuming.

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub You need to evaluate $d$. So you have to evaluate $A^{-1}b$. If you have $A^{-1}$ explicitly or in the form of, say, LU factorization of $A$, I doubt that you can do this with $O(n)$ complexity unless $A$ has some special structure.

Comment: @ Algebraic Pavel Thanks a lot for your help. If I have another issues, i'll contact you.